# Nginx and rails maintenance pages, getting Squid 2.7 to not cache them, or alternatives to squid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, squid

I'm running Squid 2.7 on a load balancer and it seems to want to happily cache anything that comes its way, including (and especially annoyingly)maintenance pages.

The maintenance pages are served through a nginx error page hook, so I don't seem to have that much control over their cache headers, I'd like to just tell squid not to cache non 200 pages. Is there a way to do that without upgrading squid? (I know newer squid has a way to match the http status on acl rules)

The page itself already has meta tags for no cache, but that doesn't seem to help squid.

Here is the bit of config from nginx that sends the error page:

```
location / {
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_friendly_error_pages off;

  recursive_error_pages on;

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }

  error_page 503 @503;
}

location @503 {
  if (-f $request_filename) {
    return 200;
    break;
  }
  error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this on nginx end, or maybe some way to add extra stuff to these error pages ot make them behave better with squid.

The general idea is that if document_root/system/maintenance.html exists, the system is in maintenance mode and that page should be rendered for all requests (except static files so that the page can reference stylesheets or images or whatnot)

As for the squid end, I don't really have anything specific to show for it, its a pretty cookie cutter setup for a caching reverse proxy.

---

On a flip note, maybe there is a better alternative to using squid, I'm open to that suggestion too.

Comment: What headers does Nginx provide back to Squid on the request for the maintenance page?  Also, have you made sure the maintenance is valid (e.g. the cache-control meta tag will be correctly interpreted)?

Comment: I *think* so .. its just a simple html page .. Did just run it through the validator and changed it to html41t instead of 5 and removed one short tag, seemed innocent enough unless squid is really hard of parsing .. maybe that will make squid validate it. Does squid by default look inside the pages and not cached them based on meta tags?

I can't really go into maintenance just for the hell of it right now to check if that helped :(

Comment: Could you post copies of both to a [gist](https://gist.github.com) or somewhere similar?

Comment: Here you go, both versions in this gist: <https://gist.github.com/1601439>

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you are looking for however something like this is much nicer on the system, this serves files then the maintenance page if it is in place then falls back to the backed server

```
try_files $uri $uri.html /maintenance.html @unicorn_story;
```

This does work well enough for us via squid but I would test it.

You could also clear squid after coming out of maintainance.

Comment: eh .. wow .. 3 years later ;) thing is I don't really have anything to do with that project anymore .. oh well ;)